# How to Hide vertices from view

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, image

I'm working on the model of a vehicle in my viewport. The reference images set on all sides of vehicle is set to only view from the Front
[image]

Now, I'm in the edit mode, my x-ray is on so that as I pick a vertex, i'm able to adjust it to the reference image.
[image]

But here is the conflict, its very hard to pick a vertex from the front as all vertices of the vehicle is showing as well.

Like I did to the reference images, is it possible to only view vertices from the front?

I cannot turn off the x-ray because that automatically hides the reference images from view.

Comment: You could enable the In Front option of the reference image in the Object panel > Viewport Visibility?

Comment: @moonboots Thank you.

Comment: If the reference image is in front of your object, you could check its Opacity on the image Data Properties panel and reduce it to around 0.2 or less then disable it in the Outliner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there's another solution but you can enable the *In Front* option of the reference image in the *Object panel > Viewport Visibility*